# using same code for fragment and activity

Tags: android

I have an activity, that I also want to use as a fragment somewhere else, do I have to rewrite the entire class to be used as both?

There needs to be two ways to get to it, the first way is from a menu where all the items are fragments.  The second way is in another part of the app it needs to go to a page with all the same functions and appearance

Comment: You can't (re)use an activity as fragment, but you can use a fragment multiple times on different places e.g. on an activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a single fragment. And reuse it in the activity, but not the other way around.

With code below you add the fragment you want to a container activity. Don't forget to check savedInstanceState if null in order to see if you are creating or recreating activity.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, YourFragment.newInstance(), YourFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
```